# How to set RepeatColumns property of a Datalist using CSS?

Tags: .net, datalist

Does anyone know how to set the RepeatColumns property of an ASP.Net Datalist using CSS ?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi - thanks for the reply. I am trying to allow simple 'theming' of a site via CSS and therefore would like to adjust the number of columns generated according to the user selected style (CSS file).

Comment: Why don't you use ASP.Net's theme system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fundamentally impossible.

This property controls how `DataList`'s server-side code renders its HTML.
CSS is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

`DataList.RepeatColumns` is a property on a server-side control.  CSS alone, being client-side, can't touch it.  In order to use CSS to style your rendered HTML, you're going to need to use the actual rendered HTML.